# Cannot add Windows8 platform to cordova project shows 'requirements check failed'

Tags: html, cordova, cordova-3

while adding windows8 platform for cordova project using commandline, requirement checked error shows ,which tells 'check reqs is not recognized as internal of external command'
the CLI commands is given below.Here I am using windows8 OS and Microsoft visual studio 2012.

```
     C:\akhil>cordova create sampleDir com.hifx.samplePro samplePro
Creating a new cordova project with name "samplePro" and id "com.hifx.samplePro"
 at location "C:\akhil\sampleDir"

C:\akhil>cd sampleDir

C:\akhil\sampleDir>cordova platform add windows8
Checking windows8 requirements...
Error: Requirements check failed: '"C:\Users\akhil\.cordova\lib\windows8\cordova
\3.4.0\windows8\bin\check_reqs"' is not recognized as an internal or external co
mmand,
operable program or batch file.

    at C:\Users\akhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\metadata\wind
ows8_parser.js:64:22
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:641:7)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:956:11)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:465:12)

C:\akhil\sampleDir>
```

Comment: Strange, it should run `check_reqs.bat`, not just `check_reqs`... What do you have in `C:\Users\akhil\.cordova\lib\windows8\cordova
\3.4.0\windows8\bin\ ` ?

Comment: ty Quickfix..problem solved.I reinstalled cordova and everything is running fine..there had some corruption in cordova file that i had installed..